# How to use unallocated drive space to install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Windows 10, and I want to install Ubuntu. I have shrunk my C: drive in Disk Management, and there is 600GB of free space on my hard drive. How do I allocate this space to Ubuntu when installing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you go up in ubuntu live mode (run this CD or USB stick).
Open gparted (management software der partitions) and create a partition on ext4 / dev / sda2 and sda3 (depends where windows is installed, you should be in \ dev \ sda1) with at least 100 GB. and create a partition for swap (logic) on / dev / sda5 (autmático to be logical).
If you do not practice, back up your data first.
As you decrease the space on your C drive (NTFS), this space had been no lease.
Then increase the size of your ext4 partition to format it.